# Get system permissions in Kotlin to get IMEI

Tags: kotlin, imei

I am working on an old project who used to get IMEI through getDeviceId(), but now I am trying to update this app, but still gets an issue about permissions, this is the code:

```
fun getImeiPreAndroid6(activity: Activity): String{

    val imei: String
    imei= ""
    telephonyManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE) as TelephonyManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val imei: String = telephonyManager!!.getImei()
    } else {
        val imei: String = telephonyManager!!.getDeviceId()
    }
    return imei
}
```

then I got this message over the getImei and getDeviceId functions:

> Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should
> explicitly check to see if permission is available (with
> checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException

and when I try to add code to check that, I got issues over the context: this.

```
 val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

 if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), 1)
  }
```

> Type mismatch. Required: Context Found: TelephonyManagerUtil

Any idea how could I do this in Kotlin please?

Comment: Do you have any specific issue or are you just looking at how to request device permissions? If so you can just read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

Comment: _"when I try to add code to check that, I got issues over the context: this"_ We can't say what's wrong with code that you haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated a piece of code.